# Question on a Maximum value/profit subarray problem in Java

Tags: java

Here is the array...

```
int[] array = new int[]{4,-1,-2,3,5,-7,1,0,0,-2,4};
```

We need to see if we can buy the stock, from the day prior. So, we should be buying at -1 and selling at 5. This will give a profit of 6.

```
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxDiff = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int diff = 0;
    int bottom = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        diff += array[i] - array[i - 1];

        System.out.println(diff);
        if (diff > maxDiff) {
            maxDiff = diff;
            max = array[i];
        }

        if (array[i] < bottom) {
            bottom = array[i];
            diff = 0;
        }
    }

    int maxx = max - maxDiff;
    System.out.println("Buy at " + maxx + " Sell at " + max);
```

This is saying I should buy at -7 and sell at 4. This would not be true.
If we buy at -7, the price would go up by 1, then stay the same, stay the same, go down by two, then up by 4. This does not earn us the most profit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It makes sense that these are relative prices given a starting price of 100 (T-1) then you should buy at -2 (101) and sell at 5 (109)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the array contains price movements then assume a starting price and calculate min/max from that

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int price = 100;
int dayIn = 0;
int dayOut = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    price += array[i];
    if (price > max) {
        max = price;
        dayOut = i;
    } 
    if (price < min) {
        min = price;
        dayIn = i;
    } 
}
if (max > min && dayIn < dayOut) { 
    System.out.printf("Buy for %d at day %d and sell on day %d for %d. Profit: %d\n", min, (dayIn + 1), (dayOut+1), max, max - min);
} else {
    System.out.println("No trade opportunity found");
}
```

Comment: upon further testing, this doesnt work

Comment: sry, i was editing my comment and then i started working on it again. but if you do an array with all positive numbers... 1,3,4,8,20 for example, it will always fall into price>max so there will never be a min. Which in stock trading, i would buy at 1 sell at 20... 1 in the min.

Comment: @soldfor, You found something I forgot to test even though I was suspicious about it. The `else` needs to go so the comparisons are done separately.

Comment: yup, thats the change i made on my end. not all of the tests work, 4,-1-2,3 doesnt work right. i can def go from here tho